# Blazor .Net Core 3.0 Preview 9 - AuthenticationStateProvider implementation issue

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-core-3.0, blazor-client-side

In our Blazor app we are overriding the default implementation of `AuthenticationStateProvider` to allow use of out Jwt.

Since upgrading to the `Preview 9` it now requires the `AthenticationResponse` response to be wrapped int a `Task`.

I have the following code;

```
public class JwtAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private bool _isUserLoggedIn = false;

    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly IAuthService _authService;
    private readonly ILogger<JwtAuthenticationStateProvider> _logger;

    public JwtAuthenticationStateProvider(HttpClient httpClient, IAuthService authService, ILogger<JwtAuthenticationStateProvider> logger)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _authService = authService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        if(!_isUserLoggedIn)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity())));
        }
        else
        {
            var tokenResponse = await _authService.GetCurrentAuthTokenAsync();

            if (tokenResponse.HasError)
            {
                var anonymousUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(anonymousUser));
            }

            var claimsResponse = await _authService.GetCurrentUserClaimsAsync();

            if(claimsResponse.HasError)
            {
                var anonymousUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
                return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(anonymousUser));
            }

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", tokenResponse.Result);
            return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claimsResponse.Result, "apiAuth"))));
        }
    }

    public async Task MarkUserAsAuthenticated()
    {
        if(!_isUserLoggedIn)
            _ = KeepSessionAsync();

        var claimsResponse = await _authService.GetCurrentUserClaimsAsync();
        var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claimsResponse.Result, "apiAuth"));
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(authenticatedUser)));
    }

    public void MarkUserAsLoggedOut()
    {
        _isUserLoggedIn = false;
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;
        var anonymousUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(anonymousUser)));
    }
}
```

However I getting the follwowing error on `GetAuthenticationStateAsync()`;

> 'JwtAuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()': return type must be 'Task' to match overridden member 'AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()'

Can anyone explain what is happening here please?

Comment: Perhaps you're mixing assemblies that you reference, and the Task you're using is not the same as the one in the base class, ie. different assemblies implement Task?

Comment: Not I don't thinks I'm referencing `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` and the meta on the `AuthenticationStateProvider` class is as well?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `await` and just have `return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claimsResponse.Result, "apiAuth"))));` ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman No it isn't it is directly extended from AuthenticationStateProvider

Answer (score 0):

An async method return a Task:

If you return : `return await Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claimsResponse.Result, "apiAuth"))));` you are returning a `Task<Task<AuthenticationState>>`

just return : `return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claimsResponse.Result, "apiAuth")));`

Your code should be :

```cs
    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        if(!_isUserLoggedIn)
        {
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity()));
        }
        else
        {
            var tokenResponse = await _authService.GetCurrentAuthTokenAsync();

            if (tokenResponse.HasError)
            {
                var anonymousUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
                return new AuthenticationState(anonymousUser);
            }

            var claimsResponse = await _authService.GetCurrentUserClaimsAsync();

            if(claimsResponse.HasError)
            {
                var anonymousUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());
                return new AuthenticationState(anonymousUser);
            }

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", tokenResponse.Result);
            return new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claimsResponse.Result, "apiAuth")));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this (as this was how it was coded before preview 9). however, this then gives the error `AuthenticationState does not contain a defination for GetAwaiter accepting a first argument of type AuthenticationState could not be found`

Comment: oups, remove await, it should work. I updated the response